# How to display only the form data on a page without the header using Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Firstly apologies I've re-edited this as the original was so vague.

What I have is a Drupal overlay which only displays a form. The issue is the overlay also displays the page header such as the logo and menu links. I don't want it to display this and was hoping someone could tell me how to prevent this without using CSS to hide the header div within that specific overlay, as although this is a temporary fix, is poor coding.

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use drupal_get_form('form_id') to get the complete html of the form in a div and use css/js to get desired result.

Comment: don't forget drupal_render(drupal_get_form('form_id')) if it didn't work for ya.